# making a burger menu disappear on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have a JS burger menu that appears if the screen width becomes smaller than 860 px. 
From this width on, the original menu changes into a stacked layout that is sliding out when the burger menu icon is clicked. The toggling in and out works fine when clicking on the burger menu icon, but I would like it to automatically disappear when the user clicks a link in the menu. Is there a way to do tis?

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<header class="scroll-effect">

        <!-- Navigation bar -->

        <div class="navigation">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row>">

                    <div class="six.columns">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/logo-nav.png" alt="BackupChecks Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="six.columns">
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#customer-portal" class="scroll-button">Customer Portal</a>
                        <a href="#service-desk" class="scroll-button">Service Desk</a>
                        <a href="#pricing" class="scroll-button">Pricing</a>
                        <a href="#contact" class="scroll-button">Contact</a>
                    </nav>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- End of navigation bar -->


        <div class="header-contents">

        <h1>
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="BackupChecks logo" class="animated bounceInDown">
        </h1>

        <h2 class="animated bounceInDown">
            The backup service desk for Asigra
        </h2>

        <div class="button-box animated fadeInUp">
            <a href="#learn-more" class="scroll-button button-green">
            Learn more
            </a>

            <a href="#pricing" class="scroll-button button-white-outline">
            Buy it now
            </a>

        </div>

        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- JS burger menu -->
        <img src="images/trigger.png" alt="Menu icon" class="trigger">
    <!-- </a> -->
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.navigation {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: +20;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
}

header.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.navigation img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: left;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    line-height: 70px;
}

nav a {
    color: #3E4750;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color ease .4s;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #66CC99;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {

nav {
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: #ffffff; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

nav a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
    }

nav {
     display: none;
}

img.trigger {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    }

}
```

And this is the javascript I have:

```
$("img.trigger").on("click", function(){

    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the links as another trigger to `slideToggle` e.g to also toggle when any `nav a` is clicked.

```
$("img.trigger, nav a").on("click", function(){

    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it also makes the navigation disappear when it's in its normal state (non burger menu) on a screen bigger than 860px.

Comment: Then you can amend accordingly by adding a class to the root element of your document or similar to then only catch links when that class is active.  You will need to employ "delegated" events for that to work though.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, I'm a newbie with JS, could you explain how to do this using the example of my code please?

Comment: Is the screen size liable to change?  If so you will need to do as I said in my first comment above, alternatively you can just make a check on `pageLoad` `$("img.trigger").on("click", function () {

    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");

});

if ($(document).width() < 860) {
    $("nav a").on("click", function () {

        $("nav").slideToggle("slow");

    });
}`

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/z9zkrk3s/

Comment: Thanks for your help. The screen size might change. Therefore I have now created a completely separate menu for smaller screen sizes that works with you first option of JS and doesn't affect the main navigation on larger screen sizes.